# How do I validate arguments to a Haskell "public safe" constructor?

Tags: python-2.7, validation, haskell, assertions

In my [Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crypto-enigma) I have a function I use to create validated instances of my class, with something like

```
@staticmethod
def config_enigma(rotor_names, window_letters, plugs, rings):

    comps = (rotor_names + '-' + plugs).split('-')[::-1]
    winds = [num_A0(c) for c in 'A' + window_letters + 'A'][::-1]
    rngs = [int(x) for x in ('01.' + rings + '.01').split('.')][::-1]

    assert all(name in rotors for name in comps[1:-1])
    assert comps[-1] in reflectors
    assert len(rngs) == len(winds) == len(comps)
    assert all(1 <= rng <= 26 for rng in rngs)
    assert all(chr_A0(wind) in LETTERS for wind in winds)

    #...
```

and I would like to enforce the same behavior in Haskell. But doing so in the same way — with assertions — does not work, because Haskell assertions are disabled in general ([unless certain compiler flags are set](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/assertions.html)). For example, in [something like](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.0.2.5/docs/src/Crypto-Enigma.html#configEnigma)

```hs
configEnigma rots winds plug rngs =
    assert ((and $ (==(length components')) <$> [length winds', length rngs']) &&
            (and $ [(>=1),(<=26)] <*> rngs') &&
            (and $ (`elem` letters) <$> winds') &&
            (and $ (`M.member` comps) <$> tail components'))
    -- ...
    where
        rngs' = reverse $ (read <$> (splitOn "." $ "01." ++ rngs ++ ".01") :: [Int])
        winds' = "A" ++ reverse winds ++ "A"
        components' = reverse $ splitOn "-" $ rots ++ "-" ++ plug
```

can't be relied on to work because the assertions will be removed in most contexts.

What is an idiomatic and reliable way to force all my instances to be validated in Haskell (using a "public safe" constructor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal thing is to express failure explicitly. For example, one might write

```hs
configEnigma :: ... -> Maybe ...
configEnigma ... = do
    guard (all (((==) `on` length) components') [winds', rngs'])
    guard (all (inRange (1,26)) rngs')
    guard (all (`elem` letters) winds')
    guard (all (`M.member` comps) (tail components'))
    return ...
    where
    ...
```

You might even consider upgrading from `Maybe` to `Except Error` for some custom-defined type `Error`, to communicate to the caller what it was that went wrong during construction. Then instead of `guard`, you could use a construction like:

```hs
    unless (all (inRange (1,26)) rngs') (throwError OutOfRange)
```

The caller to `configEnigma` will have to express how to handle failures. For `Maybe`, this looks like

```hs
case configEnigma ... of
    Just v  -> -- use the configured enigma machine v
    Nothing -> -- failure case; perhaps print a message to the user and quit
```

while with `Except` you get information about what went wrong:

```hs
case runExcept (configEnigma ...) of
    Right v  -> -- use the configured enigma machine v
    Left err -> -- failure case; tell the user exactly what went wrong based on err and then quit
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about `Except Error`? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `Except` is available from the transformers package ([documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html)). If you can say more about what you want to know about it, I'll be happy to expand further.

Comment: Seeing how `configEnigma` would look if it used `Except` (and perhaps how a caller would use it differently) will get me going.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius As discussed in the answer, the only thing that would change about how `configEnigma` looks with `Except` is that `guard` would be replaced with `unless` + `throwError`. I will add a comment on the difference in caller behavior.

Comment: Instead of `case runExcept (configEnigma ...)` can I just `configEnigma ...`, crashing if an exception is thrown from `configEnigma` (as in Python)? I'd like to avoid checking every time I call it (every check is really just going to do the same thing: grind to a halt).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Of course you can. We have a variety of fancy bottoms, including [`error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error) and [`throw`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throw). These are handy shortcuts for one-off scripts; but I strongly recommend that you avoid them in production code and get in the habit _now_ of avoiding them even in your one-offs. `Except` is a powerful tool for ensuring that you give a little thought to error-handling at just the right moment!

Comment: Yes, agreed. But it seems a bit silly (coming from Python) in ever case where my code calls `configEnigma`, if `configEnigma` has thrown an error, I want to do the same thing: just crash immediately. It makes sense to just have `configEnigma` do that itself (with a message, I suppose).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Haskell is not Python, and many things that are idiomatic to check or do at runtime in Python are idiomatically done at compile time in Haskell. Verifying that errors are handled is one such point where Python and Haskell differ (and in Haskell's favor, in my opinion).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius To really drive home Daniel Wagner's point: one step of the GHC compile process *eliminates types*. Pretty much anything involving the type system has zero performance impact! And if you use an error-aware return type (even as simple as Maybe), then Haskell can prevent many runtime-unsafe situations from ever arising in the first place.

Comment: I'll take that to heart. What should the type signature of my function then be? `configEnigma :: String -> String -> String -> String -> Either CustomError EnigmaConfig` doesn't work? Could you show me what `configEnigma` should look like using `throwError`?

Comment: And: I assume I should be using `Control.Monad.Except`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, import `Control.Monad.Except`. The type signature would look like `configEnigma :: ... -> Except CustomError EnigmaConfig`.

Comment: @TheodoreLiefGannon: OK, I'm converted (or at least on the way) but I have [a follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33724378/656912) about how to incorporate this into my [existing code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma).

Comment: I'm new to this, but catching on (I think). However in addition to [my follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33724378/656912), I'm confused about what the "best" way to handle errors like this (failures of user input that wreck everything and need to be reported) is. The [guides I've found](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/) on the Web are old, and it's not clear to me that I'm even using a "current" approach (clearly there have been changes over time).

Comment: One (final I hope) clarification. From the user's point of view, (and maybe my thinking is still to "Pythonesque"), in the case of a "smart" constructor like this one, isn't immediate failure with `error` (and signature of `... -> EnigmaConfig`) the better approach? That avoids hiding errors, makes the API much easier to use; and it's the [suggested approach in some discussions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors#Smart.28er.29_constructors).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The problem with `error` is exactly that it hides the error, in the following sense: it is not (semantically) possible to catch errors that result from `error` in pure code. So by using `error` instead of `throwError` you remove the caller's option to notice that something went wrong; callers are of course still free to ignore problems themselves if they prefer using something like `either (error . show) id`, but in at least some cases they will want to know that something went wrong and take corrective action. Why prevent that?

Comment: There are really two questions here (since I'm learning Haskell): (1) what makes sense from the design perspective, and (2) what is idiomatic Haskell. For (1) it's pretty clear that there are really two distinct scenarios, so perhaps I need *two* constrictors: (a) one for cases in which the arguments to the constructer are programmatically supplied and (b) and one for more interactive use like IHaskell or GHCi in which the user enters the arguments. For (a) I agree with what you say; but for (b) I think I need a simpler constructor that just `error`s when the arguments given are bad.

Comment: For (2) I don't know: [that link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors#Smart.28er.29_constructors) suggests `error`; but I have no idea whether that's a fair conclusion to draw. So: what do experienced Haskell users expect from a "smart" constructor, that may not be able to make a instance from supplied arguments — `... -> CustomType` with potential `error`; or `.. -> Except CustomError CustomType`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I sat and puzzled a bit over this question. I came up with two conclusions. (1) In the vast majority of cases, experienced Haskellers expect the *input* types to be sufficiently restricted that the constructor can always succeed -- e.g. make a type representing only the numbers 1-26 if you can only accept numbers 1-26, or generalize your function to work on larger numbers.

Comment: (2) The unusual cases are things like needing dependent types or having to match an existing spec that talks about failures. The canonical example of the latter is character decoding, and there it is very normal to offer both an unsafe version (which calls `error`) and a safe version (which calls `throwError`). See for example [1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html), [2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding-0.8/docs/Data-Encoding.html)

Comment: I'll give that a try, but restricting input types is fine in theory, but in practice it feels cumbersome; for example the last argument would have to change from `"01.22.15"`, say, to `(makeRingString "01.22.15")` — and worse, thanks to the issue with `read` discussed above, if the user alternatively did  `(read "01.22.15" :: RingString )` he'd learn nothing about what went wrong. Moreover,`makeRingString` is just going to have to either `error` (which just shifts the issue) or have be `... -> Except Error makeRingString` and the latter just makes the call even more complicated.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Like IO, if there's a chance of having an error, you can't get away from that chance just by wishing. You just have to face up to the possibility of errors and be as graceful as you can.

Comment: Yes, so clearly the two scenarios are so different that two constructors are needed. Also, any thoughts on why [that article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors#Smart.28er.29_constructors) gives `error` as the way to do this?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius *shrug* Ask the authors.