# How do I call a constructor that may fail, especially when implementing 'Read' and 'Arbitrary'?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, exception, quickcheck

I have a "public safe" that may fail with a (potentially informative) errors:

```
data EnigmaError = BadRotors
                 | BadWindows
                 | MiscError String

instance Show EnigmaError where
  show BadRotors = "Bad rotors"
  show BadWindows = "Bad windows"
  show (MiscError str) = str

configEnigma :: String -> String -> String -> String -> Except EnigmaError EnigmaConfig
configEnigma rots winds plug rngs = do
        unless (and $ [(>=1),(<=26)] <*> rngs') (throwError BadRotors)
        unless (and $ (`elem` letters) <$> winds') (throwError BadWindows)
        -- ...
        return EnigmaConfig {
                components = components',
                positions = zipWith (\w r -> (mod (numA0 w - r + 1) 26) + 1) winds' rngs',
                rings = rngs'
        }
    where
        rngs' = reverse $ (read <$> (splitOn "." $ "01." ++ rngs ++ ".01") :: [Int])
        winds' = "A" ++ reverse winds ++ "A"
        components' = reverse $ splitOn "-" $ rots ++ "-" ++ plug
```

but it is unclear how I should call this, particularly (and specifically) in implementing `Read` and `Arbitrary` (for QuickCheck).

For the former, I can get as far as

```
instance Read EnigmaConfig where
        readsPrec _ i = case runExcept (configEnigma c w s r) of
            Right cfg  -> [(cfg, "")]
            Left err -> undefined
          where [c, w, s, r] = words i
```

but this seems to end up hiding error information available in `err`; while for the latter, I'm stuck at

```
instance Arbitrary EnigmaConfig where
        arbitrary = do
                nc <- choose (3,4)  -- This could cover a wider range
                ws <- replicateM nc capitals
                cs <- replicateM nc (elements rotors)
                uk <- elements reflectors
                rs <- replicateM nc (choose (1,26))
                return $ configEnigma (intercalate "-" (uk:cs))
                                      ws
                                      "UX.MO.KZ.AY.EF.PL"  -- TBD - Generate plugboard and test <<<
                                      (intercalate "." $ (printf "%02d") <$> (rs :: [Int]))
```

which fails with a mismatch between the expected and actual types:

> Expected type: Gen EnigmaConfig
>   Actual type: Gen (transformers-0.4.2.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Except.Except Crypto.Enigma.EnigmaError EnigmaConfig)

How do I call a ("public safe") constructor when it may fail, particularly when using it in implementing `Read` and `Arbitrary` for my class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Read` typeclass represents parses as lists of successes (with failures being the same as no successes); so rather than `undefined` you should return `[]`. As for losing information about what went wrong: that's true, and the type of `readsPrec` means you can't do much about that. If you really, really wanted to [note: I don't think you should want this] you could define a newtype wrapper around `Except EnigmaError EnigmaConfig` and give that a `Read` instance that had successful parses of configuration errors.

For `Arbitrary` you have a couple choices. One choice is so-called rejection sampling; e.g.

```
arbitrary = do
    -- ...
    case configEnigma ... of
        Left err -> arbitrary -- try again
        Right v  -> return v
```

You might also consider an `Arbitrary` instance to be part of your internal API, and use unsafe, internal calls rather than using the safe, public API for constructing your configuration. Other options include calling `error` or `fail`. (I consider these four options to be in roughly preference order -- rejection sampling, then unsafe internal calls, then `error`, then `fail` -- though your judgement may differ.)

Comment: Since `read` should fail completely, and since want to inform, rather than `undefined` or `[]`, what about `error (show err)`? Also in the case of `Arbitrary`, since I'm generating only valid values for the arguments, I want it to fail immediately rather than quietly try another; so `error (show err)` rather than `arbitrary`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius If you want to write a parser with informative errors, you are free to; you just can't (shouldn't) call it `read`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed that in the docs for `Read`: no matter what the cause, `read` should fail with "no parse" (and `readsPrec` should return `[]`, as you say: ["If there is no successful parse, the returned list is empty."](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readsPrec)). That's too bad for the user, imv, (since information is lost); but those are the rules I guess.

Comment: For `Arbitrary EnigmaConfig ` though, if I'm generating arguments that all out to be valid, I certainly don't want to do rejection sampling (as cool as that is): I just want to fail (I think): it would be a true coding error.

Comment: (Note that the loss of info in `readsPrec`, and potentially other cases , can be avoided if the constructer fails with `error` – see my recent comment to the [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33713265/656912).)